# \attachfile add an annotation instead of attachment in the final PDF

Tags: pdf, attachfile

I whant to attach a file to the final PDF produced whit XeLaTeX, so I used the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attachfile2}


\begin{document}
  \attachfile{foo.txt}{bar}
\end{document}
```

But, after compilation, I get instead of an attachment an annotation:

[image: Evince screenshot showing the annotation near “bar” in the produced PDF]

As you see, my command produce an annotation and the file content is nowhere.

So, how can I add with `attachfile2` package an attachment and not an annotation?

Comment: Your example works for me on overleaf. What happens when you double click the icon? There seems to be no clear terminology what an "Attachment" is and what an "annotation" is.

Comment: @nhck [this is annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Annotation) and [file attachement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#File_attachments).

Comment: @nhck  Basically, *annotations* it’s what appear in annotation’s field in a PDF reader and *attachment* it’s what appeared in attachment’s field.

Answer (score 1):

Use the embedfile package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\begin{document}
\embedfile{test-ansi.tex} text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use `xelatex` to compile and `embedfile` seems designed for `pdflatex`. So it doesn’t work.

Comment: use lualatex, or wait a few month, then it will perhaps work for xelatex too.